# get multiple string with start char in line with visual basics

Tags: vba, visual-studio

i'am trying get multiple string in line,

example string read from text file `(TextBox3.Text)`

code :
`<data size="xx" path="path" filename="filename" />`

is there any way to get the  selected strings

my code `  Dim waca() As String = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(TextBox3.Text)

```
            For Each baris As String In waca

                If baris.Contains("<data") Then
                    Dim remchar As String


                    MsgBox(remchar)

                End If
            Next
```

`

i want the output is

`xx path filename` in text file

Comment: There are a number of ways you could go about extracting one string from another.  Which one to choose depend on your situation.  Are you reading from a text file or a text box? (Or a text file named `(TextBox3.Text)`?)  Will the string **always** be exactly the same? (ie., 3 items in a row, same order?)  Where is this data getting there?  Is this some form of xml? I f so, where's the rest of the file?  It would probably make this easier if you share some sample data so it's clear what you're trying to do.

Comment: Does the `Contains(...)` method do the same as `InStr(...)` does? You could also try splitting the string by " and check the results.

Comment: the string is not always same.but     i tried  remchar = baris.Replace("""", "").Replace("<", "").Replace("/>", "").Replace("data", "").Replace("=", "").Replace("size", "").Replace("path", "") and it work perfectly